# How to Sorting 'paragraph' entries

Tags: xml, xslt

**Here we have xml input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Table of contents for operating manual, </label><lc>1.21</lc></p>
<p sec-level="primaryEntry"><label>Paragraph in engagement letter confirming that entity to be formed will be the client, </label><lc>1.29</lc></p>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Paragraph in engagement letter confirming that entity to be formed will be separate client, </label><lc>1.31</lc></p>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Consent to representation and conflict waiver letter for foundation formed for existing client, </label><lc>1.32</lc></p>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Consent to use of name, </label><lc>5.8</lc></p>
<p sec-level="primaryEntry"><label>Appointment of initial directors and adoption of bylaws, </label><lc>5.11</lc></p>
<p sec-level="primaryEntry"><label>Waiver of notice and consent to holding first meeting of board of directors, </label><lc>5.12</lc></p>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Heading and participants, </label><lc>5.13</lc></p>
<p sec-level="secondaryEntry"><label>Adoption of waiver of notice and consent to meeting, </label><lc>5.14</lc></p>
</body>
```

**Expected Output**
We want to sorting based on attribute p/@sec-level value.

Comment: So where exactly are you having a problem with this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I'm unable to do sorting can you help us.

Comment: No, I will not write your code for you. If you have a **specific** question, ask it.

Comment: @MohdJaved What have you tried so far? Sorting is explained in the spec : https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#sorting

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: @Existing input we need as expected but additional added alphabetical order in the  bunch.

Answer (score 0):

For example, try to use a temp root-variabel that has a help-attribute to sort on: (assumption: all primaryEntry should come first)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="withOrderByAttributes">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="withOrderByAttributes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$withOrderByAttributes/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p"  mode="withOrderByAttributes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="orderBy">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@sec-level='primaryEntry'"><xsl:text>1</xsl:text></xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>2</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates >
        <xsl:sort select="@orderBy"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="withOrderByAttributes" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="withOrderByAttributes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```